# Insert a row with two columns every four ng-repeat values

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the next code in Html and AngularJS:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6' ng-repeat='post in news'>
        <div class='post-content'>{{ post.title }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I need is to push a row with two columns every four posts.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='add-content'>Something</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='add-content'>Something</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do it in AngularJS?

The DOM result what I'm looking for is:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
       <div class='add-content'>Something</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='add-content'>Something</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
    </div>
...
```

Comment: Where is your ngRepeat? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where does content come from for `class='add-content'` ?

Answer (score 2):

essentially you need to be using the built in $index which keeps track on the index it is currently on. Every fourth item implies it should be divisible by four. You also need an ng-if statement to determine wether a dom snippet should be added on said item. Also this calls for the use of the ng-repeat-start instead of ng-repeat. Its seldom used but for this purpose it should work.  Code below :

```
   <div class='row' ng-repeat-start="post in news" >
      <div class='post-content'>{{ post.title }}</div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row" ng-repeat-end  ng-if="($index +1 ) % 4 === 0" >
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='post-content'>POST TITLE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Modulo is a nice approach but it's not working as the user expects.

Comment: It should be `($index+1) % 4 === 0`. You are lucky, I was up to post exactly the same answer ;)

Comment: This doesn't produce expected results

Comment: what makes you say that? @charlietfl ?